# Ads reducing by more than half on Iphone?

Tags: iphone

For some odd season, the Ads, either IADs, or from ADmob not showing as often as it used to on my apps on IPhone.

The number dropped by more than half.

Obviously my revenue is tanking result of that,

what could go wrong?

Comment: This *seems* [off-topic for Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq/). Perhaps the iOS forums would be a better place to discuss this? Or, *maybe*, over at [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com)...

Answer (score 1):

Advertisers are not seeing as much return on their ad investment and as a result are not advertising as much? But I guess that's not really a programming problem, sorry.

Your not unnecessarily restricting the ad content are you?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of app are we talking about here? We've found out the hard way that iAds do not appear a lot in app designed for kids and the logic I remember for that is that kids aren't really the intended audience for the advertisements.